# function template parameter loses const when template argument is explicity passed?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

```
template <typename T>
void test(const T& x) {}

int a {};
int& ref = a;
const int& c_ref = a;

test(c_ref)  // T = int, x = const int&
test<int&>(ref); // T = int& , x = int&
```

Why does the function template parameter x loses the `const` qualifier?

Comment: If you aren't interested in a specific standard version, please don't use version tags. "C++" alone is already of the meaning "latest".

Comment: Sorry sir, First time to stackoverflow

Comment: No need to apologize. Just a heads up. Hope you stick around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the explicit (non-deduced) instantiation

```
test<int&>(ref);
```

this is the (theoretical) signature you get

```
void test<int&>(const (int&)& x)
```

which shows that the `const`-qualification applies to the whole `(int&)`, and not only the `int`. `const` applies to what is left, and if there's nothing, it applies to what is right: `int&`, but as a whole - there, it applies to `&`, again because `const` applies to what's on its left. But there are no `const` references (they aren't changeable at all, i.e., they can't rebind), the `const` is dropped, and reference collapsing rules contract the two `&` into one.

Comment: I wish I remembered who it was that first told me this, because there is credit due there. But I'll re-iterate it still: leading const is misleading.

Comment: Yeah, same issue with `const auto p = getPointer()`, which I certaily do from time to time instead of `const auto* p`.

Comment: I get the reference collapsing part and the rebind part. I can't get the remaining. Would you mind explaining that again? Thanks

Comment: The main point there is that the `const` in the original template belongs to `T` (because you say so in `template <typename T> void test(const T& x)`). When you instantiate with `test<int&>`, then `T` is `int&`. That turns the function parameter into `const (int&) &`. This `const (int&)` is the same as `(int&) const`, which is `int & const`, and there, `const` applies to `&` and is hence dropped. Is that clearer?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yep, this is why east const is best const, it allows substitution to do the right thing. `T const&` for `T=int&` is `int& const&` and it's more clear that the `const` is applying to the `&`.