# How to handle pointing types with templates, and const keywords?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I wanted to do a simple thing with templates and got surprised how not simple it is.
I have got :

- An array which size is 9, let's say type const int *

I want it to pass it as an argument for an object construction, like so:

```cpp
const int * myArray[9];
//filling array;
ObectType<int*> myObject(&myArray[0]);
```

With object constructor here :

```cpp
template<class T>
class ObjectType
{
public:
   ObjectType(const T * myArray) : myArrayMember(myArray) {};
   const T * myArrayMember;
}
```

But I get the following error :

```cpp
error: invalid conversion from ‘const int**’ to ‘int* const*’ [-fpermissive]
   86 |     ObectType<int*> myObject(&myArray[0]);
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~
      |                                 |
      |                                 const int**
```

Shouldn't const T * be replaced by const int** ?
I have tried to keep it simple, the real code is more complicated. Tell me if you need some information.

Comment: You fell into a similar trap as the person who asked this https://stackoverflow.com/q/64893722/817643

Comment: Because my array contains pointer. And to pass an array that contains pointers as an argument, you need to have int** copiedArray = &realArray[0], where real array is declared like so : int * realArray[x];

Comment: The answer in the link you sent, StoryTeller, is way more complicated than the one I got. Thank you, though !

Comment: The answer your got falls short on describing the trap (although it does follow a better convention implicitly). There's a reason memes like "leading const is misleading" and "east const is best const" permeate. Do yourself a favor and adopt a convention that works along side human intuition when doing substitution..

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That's a very good point. I should have made that explicit in the first place. I've edited the answer to address that aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `myObject` you are specifying the template parameter `T` with the argument `int*`. When substituted into the constructor argument `T const *`, this gives `int * const *`, which is incorrect.

You need `T` to be `int const *`, and you need to provide the correct template argument:

```
ObjectType<int const *> myObject(&myArray[0]);
```

Or from C++17, you can let it be deduced:

```
ObjectType myObject(&myArray[0]);
```

---

As mentioned in a [comment by StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374249/how-to-handle-pointing-types-with-templates-and-const-keywords/65374304#comment115577860_65374249), it's worth pointing out that the explanation in this answer seems obvious because I have chosen to use the "east const" notation which I find much more preferable for a number of reasons. You can read this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162480) for more details.

In this case, the benefit of this notation is that understanding how template argument substitution works becomes easier, and the correct substitution becomes more obvious.